# How to add "assumed true" statements in Coq

Tags: coq

I tried to add a definition of a natural number in CoqIDE.

```
Inductive nat : Set :=
  | O: nat
  | S: nat -> nat.
```

But I couldn't add this as "assumed true":

```
forall (n m: nat, S n = S m -> n = m).
```

How do I add this?

Comment: I'm not completely clear on what you want to do, but your formula is not syntactically correct. I believe you meant `forall (n m: nat), S n = S m -> n = m.` (note the parenthesis' placement). Your statement is actually provable, no need to assume it:
`Lemma S_inj : forall (n m: nat), S n = S m -> n = m.
Proof. intros n m [=]. assumption. Qed.` The `[=]` intro pattern expresses the built-in injectivity of the `S` constructor.

Comment: @ana-borges This should probably be posted as an answer! ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely clear on what you want to do, but your formula is not syntactically correct. I believe you meant `forall (n m: nat), S n = S m -> n = m` (note the parenthesis' placement).

Your statement is actually provable, no need to assume it:

```
Lemma S_inj : forall (n m: nat), S n = S m -> n = m.
Proof. intros n m [=]. assumption. Qed.
```

The `[=]` [intro pattern](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#intropattern-inj-discr-ex) expresses the built-in injectivity of the `S` constructor.